# splitting python 1d array into 2d array by comma

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python (experience in c#), and I have a list in a text file that I dumped into a list using;

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

The thing is, every line is in the form XXXXX, XXXXX (with varying lengths of XXXXX), and I want to convert f into a 2-dimensional array with things in the line before the comma in the first dimension and everything after in the second.

What's the best practice for doing something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Just use [`.split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

From the documentation, we can see that the `string` method `.split` will:

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

So to give an example, taking the `string`:

```
s = "abcd, efgh"
```

then we can do:

```
s.split(', ')
```

to get a `list`:

```
['abcd', 'efgh']
```

So for your application, just throw it in the `list-comprehension`:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip().split(', ') for x in content]
```